# Kronecker product rule

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times s}$, and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{pr\times qs}$. Consider:
\begin{equation}
(A\otimes B)C^{\top}.
\end{equation}
I'm wondering if there are any rules for how one can compute the above expression. I initially thought that the following would hold:
\begin{equation}
(A\otimes B)C^{\top}=(AC^{\top}\otimes B),
\end{equation}
however, $AC^{\top}$ is not a well-defined matrix product per dimensions. So what can one do instead?

Comment: I think you meant to write either $\,(A\otimes B)C^T\,$ or $\,(A\otimes B)^TC,\,$ otherwise the dimensions are not compatible for a matrix product.

Comment: @greg Yes, of course. I've fixed it now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One common trick is to write $C$ as a sum of the form
$$
C = \sum_{i=1}^n P_i \otimes Q_i
$$
With each $P_i$ of size $p\times q$ and each $Q_i$ of size $r \times s$. With that, we can rewrite
$$
(A \otimes B)C^{\top} = (A \otimes B)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n P_i \otimes Q_i\right)^{\top} = 
\sum_{i=1}^n (AP_{i}^{\top}) \otimes (BQ_{i}^{\top}).
$$
If we take $P_i$ to be the standard basis of matrices over $\Bbb R^{p \times q}$ (i.e. the matrices with exactly one non-zero entry), then writing $C$ as this sum corresponds to breaking it down into block-entries.

Comment: Should $n$ not be equal to $pq$?

Comment: In general, $n$ doesn’t need to be larger than $pq$ or $rs$. For the purposes of this answer, I intentionally avoided addressing this